# need to get total rows of a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i'm new in asp.net C#, i need to get total rows for gridview and also current row of grid...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um:

```
gridView.Rows.Count

gridView.SelectedIndex  -- gives the index of the current row.
```

Comment: No problem - feel free to accept the answer (big tick beside it), if you think it's correct.